# Upload PDF and save to database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to upload a pdf to a database. I keep getting the "error while uploading file" error. Non of the data gets inserted into the database either.

Please can some one who is not so new to PHP and SQL have a look and tell me where I have gone wrong.

At a later stage I will be trying to merge a few pfds together and then save the new combined pdf to the database.

SQL for table

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_request` (
  `InvoiceNum` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userEmail` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Progress` enum('Uploaded','Verified and Awaiting Payment','Submitted to Department','Closed') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Uploaded',
  `UploadDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `FileName` varchar(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

PHP code

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
    $user_home->redirect('index.php');
}

if($_SESSION['userRole'] !== ('user'))
{
    $user_home->redirect('index.php');
}

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">

    <body>                                  
<div id="body">
    <form action="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <button type="submit" name="btn-upload">upload</button>
    </form>
    <br /><br />
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['success']))
    {
        ?>
        <label>File Uploaded Successfully...  <a href="view.php">click here to view file.</a></label>
        <?php
    }
    else if(isset($_GET['fail']))
    {
        ?>
        <label>Problem While File Uploading !</label>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <label>Please only upload PDF files</label>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
 <?php
        if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
    {  
    if ($_FILES['file']['type'] == "application/pdf") {  
        $update=date("Ymdhis");
        $mail =$row['userEmail'];
        $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_request(userEmail,UploadDate) VALUES('$mail','$update)";
        mysql_query($sql); 
        $file = $update."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $folder="uploads/";
        $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
        $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);        
        if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
        {
            $sql="UPDATE tbl_uploads SET(FileName) VALUES('$final_file') WHERE UploadDate = $update";
            mysql_query($sql);
            ?>
            <script>
            alert('successfully uploaded');
            window.location.href='index.php?success';
            </script>
            <?php
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
            <script>
            alert('error while uploading file');
            window.location.href='index.php?fail';
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }
    else{
    ?>
            <script>
            alert('Only pdf files may be uploaded');
            window.location.href='index.php?fail';
            </script>
            <?php
    }
}
?>

    </body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I eventually got my code working, here it is for any one who may need to do the same thing in the future.

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
    {  

    if ($_FILES['file']['type'] == "application/pdf") {  
        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
        $update=date("Ymdhis");
        $mail =$row['userEmail'];
        $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_request(userEmail,uploadDate) VALUES('$mail','$update')";
        mysqli_query($link,$sql);
        $file = $update."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $folder="upload/";
        $final_file = strtolower($file);
        //$final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);  

        if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))       {

            $sql2="UPDATE tbl_request SET FileName ='".$final_file."' WHERE uploadDate = '".$update."'";
            mysqli_query($link,$sql2);
            ?>
            <script>
            alert('successfully uploaded');
            //window.location.href='index.php?success';
            </script>
            <?php
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
            <script>
            alert('error while uploading file');
            //window.location.href='index.php?fail';
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }
    else{
    ?>
            <script>
            alert('Only pdf files may be uploaded');
            //window.location.href='index.php?fail';
            </script>
            <?php
    }
}
?>
```

The two things that I would like change:

1. The `$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");` for `mysqli_query($link,$sql);` I am sure there is a way to get this info from dbconfig.php (I'm just not sure how)
2. I would like people to be able to upload 3 pdf's, then have php code to merge them into one that is then saved like above.

Comment: the last parts of your answer are what seem to be questions. Is this your solution or was this intended as an edit to the question?

Comment: It was a solution plus what updates I would like to make.

Answer (score -1):

Technically you aren't storing the pdf in the database, but only a reference to the files stored location. So to get the error you are getting, your  `if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))` must be failing, possibly its a path problem, it looks like you are specifying a relative path,

```
try an absolute (full path) ie windows C:\folder\ or linux /home/user/public_html/uploads/
```